# An "exec bash" works on a bash command line, but not in a script. The tool refuses to respond: "provided file is not a console". What workaround?

Tags: bash, shell, docker, console

I would like to send a command to a *Rancher* container to learn about its files.

When I run it on a `bash` command line :

```bsh
rancher --url ... --access-key ... --secret-key ... --env 1a5 exec 1i845011 bash -c 'find /opt/ -name states.xml'
```

It returns me the wished file list.

But when I run it inside a `.sh` script, in this following way or surrounded by ` instead, it fails :

```bsh
# The command line that is in my .sh script :
ALL_STATES_FILES=$(rancher $AUTHENTICATION --env $ID exec $CONTAINER_ID bash -c "find /opt/ -name states.xml")

# fails, mentioning this if I ran my script with a `bash -x` :
rancher --url ... --access-key ... --secret-key ... --env 1a5 exec 1i845011 bash -c 'find /opt/ -name states.xml'
ALL_STATES_FILES='time="2021-02-11T14:41:56+01:00" level=fatal msg="provided file is not a console" '
```

I've attempted to add `-t` and `-i` options after `exec`, but without success.

That strange message, "*provided file is not a console*", *seems* to come from a *Go* script/source if I search about it over the Internet. Therefore, it *could* be a bug of the *Rancher 1.6* I'm using or of the *Go* version it uses.

Whatever, do I have a workaround in my `.sh` script to lure the `rancher` with the command I'm sending to it? Make it believe that it's a Console output that it is targeting, for the importance it seems to have for it?

Comment: What does the help of  `rancher` says about the `exec` option? It would seem that you are passing a string first (not a "*console*") to the `exec`. Shouldn't be `exec bash...`?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity the parameter coming immediately after exec is the container id target. And the command line is working written like it is on a bash command line. If the parameter was misplaced, it should fail there too.

Comment: Try `echo`ing the command instead of running it. Are all variables correctly defined?

Comment: @terdon They are, and it's the `bash -x` (that shows each line executed in debug) that I've copied verbatim to execute the line that reveals itself working well on a bash console.

Comment: I don't see the actual command with the variables expanded anywhere. Your example with `bash -x`  shows `ALL_STATES_FILES='time="2021-...`, I need to see `ALL_STATES_FILES=$(rancher foobar...` where `foobar` is the value of the `$AUTHENTICATION` variable. I suspect that some of your variables are not set as you expect and that is why you are getting this error.

Comment: It looks to me like the `rancher` portion of the command behaves differently in a subshell than outside of one.

Comment: @terdon I show you the command that causes a trouble. I cannot expand `$AUTHENTICATION` variable content here, because it contains informations related to the organization I'm working in. But be sure I checked it was fully expanded.

Comment: Can you at least show the contents of the other variables? Does it help if you quote all variables properly like this: `ALL_STATES_FILES=$(rancher "$AUTHENTICATION" --env "$ID" exec "$CONTAINER_ID" bash -c "find /opt/ -name states.xml")`? Do any of your variables have spaces? Can you show us the _actual_ output of `bash -x` which has the command split into arguments as passed to the shell? You can replace the sensitive bits with NNN, what we need is the structure of the command as parsed by bash.

Comment: It seems that that ranger tool insists that its stdout be a terminal, not a pipe. Does it give the same error message if you run it as `ranger ... | cat`?

Comment: If that's the problem, you can run it in a terminal and still capture its output by running the command via `script /dev/null`.

Comment: @user414777 you mean that I could try also something like that? `rancher --url ... --access-key ... --secret-key ... --env 1a5 exec 1i845011 bash -c 'find /opt/ -name states.xml'` or `rancher --url ... --access-key ... --secret-key ... --env 1a5 exec 1i845011 script /dev/null 'find /opt/ -name states.xml'` ? What would have worked too?

Comment: No, I was meaning that you should emrun the whole command via script e.g. `var=$(script /dev/null -qc 'stty -onlcr; rancher ... args ...')`. `script` does pretty much rhe same as `unbuffer`, only that is doesn't need installing. Correctly quoting the command is a bit trickier though, as with ssh.

Comment: @user414777 please post that as an answer. It seems like a good solution and it will be lost here in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

I did not found the underlying reason, but a colleague of mine found the workaround for that issue.

- Install the package `expect`.
- Add the `unbuffer` command before `rancher`

This, is working in a script :

```bsh
ALL_STATES_FILES=$(unbuffer rancher $AUTHENTICATION --env $ID exec $CONTAINER_ID bash -c "find /opt/ -name states.xml")
```